# Finding the actual call from flask to run on port 5000

Tags: python, flask

This question might be a little wierd, but guy whome I do not have contact with wrote a program, which I should adapt.

it started a local python program, which runs with flask on port 5000 so when i write :5000 I can access a webpage with a few buttons but the .py file I found doesn`t set a port anywhere within the program it only calls:

```
app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

and a couple of

```
@app.route('/DoSomething', methods=['POST', 'GET']
```

in the folder are a few more files, which doesnt contain a port either ... when I type

```
cat ./* | grep :5000
```

I find a few lines, but I have no plan where they are coming for

I am not really an expert on this topic - never worked with flask or created any applications that can be accessed with an URL ... Does someone probably know what I am missing here / where I probably find more?

Comment: The default port of flask is 5000.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/
So when he does not specify any port, it will run it on 5000.

Comment: It's the default value in the `run` method defined in flask ... https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1fa9185c7e82ecc43b99d797af5584133458008d/flask/app.py#L924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the line you reference does not include a value for the `port` keyword argument, it is defaulted to port 5000 which is the expected behavior [per the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.run).

In terms of finding the actual line where this happens, that line is in the `run` method of the `Flask` application object in the [flask source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1fa9185c7e82ecc43b99d797af5584133458008d/flask/app.py#L924):

```
_host = '127.0.0.1'
_port = 5000
server_name = self.config.get('SERVER_NAME')
sn_host, sn_port = None, None

if server_name:
    sn_host, _, sn_port = server_name.partition(':')

host = host or sn_host or _host
port = int(port or sn_port or _port)
```

This code defaults host and port and then overrides them based on the `SERVER_NAME` defined in the application config or the passed host and port information.

**A note on your grep one-liner**

This is off-topic to the initial question, but:

```
cat ./* | grep :5000
```

Should be re-written as:

```
grep 5000 ./*
```

Which will annotate the matching lines with the filename, and save you a useless use of cat.

Comment: thanks, guess I could have searched a few more hours and wouldnt have found the code than hehe